# Unable to edit and see content of pages

Tags: editor

I am not able to see the content of my WordPress pages. Only header and footer is showing on my web pages.

When I am visiting these pages I am not able to see any content except header and footer part. Also I am not able to edit the content of pages from page editor because its showing blank screen and not loading the editor panel. See below screenshot:

[image]

The strange thing is that when I change the theme of my website then everything is working fine. I have a doubt there is some problem in my current theme but I don't know what the issue is. Please help me in resolving the query.

Comment: There's not enough information here for someone without access to your site to diagnose. You have taken a good troubleshooting step in switching themes and discovering that some code in your theme is affecting those pages. See if you can isolate it further, i.e. instead of disabling the entire theme, try removing sections of code that may have to do with page content. When you find a section of code that seems to be the culprit (removing it fixes the error, replacing it makes it happen) share that code with us.

Comment: Welcome to WordPress Stack Exchange! We love to help you. Problem is when you don't know what the issue is, how should we know from afar? We need a reproducible problem. That said, as your question is currently written it simply is too broad. Also please don't include links to your live site as they may be considered malicious or spam and have no value as soon as your issue got fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is most certainly an issue with your theme then.

To figure out what the error is (assumption is it's a JavaScript error), right click anywhere on the page, and then select **Inspect**

This will open the developer tools window, click on the **Console** tab, and then refresh the page.  You should see some type of error in red that probably gives a slight bit of detail as to what the error is.

You should then contact your theme developer for support and provide them with details as to the issue you're having, plus anything you found in the console

Comment: I have followed the steps suggested by you but i am not able to find any javascript errors on website . Nothing is showing in red on console tab

Comment: When i go to wordpress page editor panel and click on console tab then following javascript errors are showing . Can anyone please help me in explaining what are these errors and how to resolve these errors

https://imgur.com/jzCzPQ4
https://imgur.com/bkzEl15
https://imgur.com/3miBebV

Comment: @ashishabg try disabling wp seo premium, also access your site using http:// instead of https:// as there's something (plugin or theme) including non-secure items -- which may be part of the issue.

Comment: Also looks like moment, and few other libs are not being loaded.  Best to try the http:// first to see if that resolves the issue (as if you use https and site tries to load http resource, it will not load it sometimes).  Next you should contact theme dev as it looks like that's the issue

Comment: Hi , I have disabled the WP SEO premium plugin but no luck . Also i want to let you know that i have deleted some defer javascript code from wp config file. After deleting defer javascript code wordpress page editor is working fine and displaying content on editor.

Comment: In web browser console its also showing below java script error 


Uncaught TypeError: jQuery is not a function
    at common.js?ver=5.1.1:3
    at dispatch (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:3)
    at r.handle (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:3)

Comment: @ashishabg that is because jQuery file is not loaded yet (or not loaded at all)